# Elegant way building url request with parameters

Tags: .net, url, parameters, build

There must me a more elegant way to build a URL with parameters in .NET then for example

`Response.Write("<a href=HeadOfMarketView.aspx"+Session["HOM"] != null ? Session["HOM"]+">Head of Market</a> / ")`

I mean the concatenation of strings is a litte bit old school, no?

Comment: sorry the right expression is

Response.Write("<a href=HeadOfMarketView.aspx"+(Session["HOM"] != null ? "?"+Session["HOM"]:"")+">Head of Market</a> / ");

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is better:

```
Response.Write(string.Format("<a href=HeadOfMarketView.aspx?param={0}>Head of Market</a>", Session["HOM"] as string ?? "" ));
```

EDIT: Response to the comment (C# 3.0, .NET 3.5):

```
Response.Write(string.Format("<a href=HeadOfMarketView.aspx{0}>Head of Market</a>", Session["HOM"].ToUrlParamString()));

public static class UrlHelper
{
    public static string ToUrlParamString(this object val)
    {
        return val != null ? "?" + val : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need a solution where the parameter is only generated when the variable (in this case Session["HOM"]) is not null